# Texture for UnorderedAccessView

Tags: c#, directx, sharpdx

I would need to create an `UnorderedAccessView` for use as output of a compute shader:

```
  var target = new Texture2D(device, new Texture2DDescription() {
    Width = bitmap.PixelWidth,
    Height = bitmap.PixelHeight,
    ArraySize = 1,
    MipLevels = 1,
    Format = Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm,
    SampleDescription = new SampleDescription() { Count = 1, Quality = 0 },
    BindFlags = BindFlags.UnorderedAccess | BindFlags.ShaderResource,
    Usage = ResourceUsage.Dynamic
  });
  var targetView = new UnorderedAccessView(device, target);
```

The first line keeps resulting in a *Parameter is incorrect* exception. Debug device and layer are switched on, there is no more useful debug or error message. Creating the texture without `BindFlags.UnorderedAccess` works but that's not what I need.

I tried all possible combinations of the flags, including but not limited to:

```
    Format = Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm,
    BindFlags = BindFlags.UnorderedAccess,
    Usage = ResourceUsage.Default
```

Nothing runs if `BindFlags.UnorderedAccess` is asked for.

DX11.2, Shader 5.

Comment: Add the DeviceCreationFlags.Debug flag to device creation and it will tell you why it can't be created. From memory, ResourceUsage.Dynamic definitely won't work, so stick to Default. I'm not sure BGRA works either, did you try RGBA8 with Usage Default?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not. As I described up front, debug is switched on and there is no better error message than this. Yes, MSDN says RGBA is supported, so that was my first attempt. I tried all usages, all CPU access flags, even those that are logically impossible together. :-)

Comment: What feature level did you create your device at? What GPU is this you're trying it on?

Comment: We might be on to something? 11. Now I got a glimpse of another message than what I saw earlier all the time, this one speaks about levels all right. Right now I'm in a virtual machine but I checked, dxdiag says DX11 all right, with supports ticked off. I didn't except performance, just proper initialization but I might be wrong after all...

Comment: You've checked graphicsDevice.FeatureLevel and it returned D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0? I'm not asked what API you're using or even what the card claims to support, I'm asking what Feature Level the device reports after you've created it.

Comment: Oh, dear me, never thought to check that. It's 9_3, for crying out loud. :-) Small wonder then. OK then, thanks for the solution, I'll move one to another machine and will keep an eye out for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The device was created at Feature Level 9_3 which does not support UAVs or Compute Shaders.